# Magnitude of potential four-vector in Lorenz gauge

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, covariance

The Klein-Gordon equation is based on the relation
$(E-e\phi)^2-(pc-eA)^2=m^2c^4$, which is the magnitude of the difference between the momentum four-vector and the four-potential.
Since the magnitude of the momentum four-vector is given by
$E^2-p^2c^2=m^2c^4$, does it follow that the magnitude of the four-potential is zero? If so, does this follow from choosing the Lorenz gauge?

Comment: Duplicate of a closed question,  [Vector potential in the Klein-Gordon potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/532751/vector-potential-in-the-klein-gordon-potential), by the same OP.

Comment: Thomas, when a question gets closed, you should edit it rather than post another similar question. This is explained in the closure message.